# Printing the value of QUrl in gdb

Tags: qt, gdb, qstring

I want to look up the value of QUrl type. QUrl has a toString method which returns a QString.Using something like this should have produced desired results

```
printq4string urlvar.toString()
```

How to do you print the value of QString in gdb ?

Answer (score 0):

There are GDB pretty printers for Qt types: http://nikosams.blogspot.ru/2009/10/gdb-qt-pretty-printers.html